# .NET Core and VSCode Can't Create Projects - Command Line Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I downloaded VSCode and .NET CORE.zip to explore ASP5. I'm on a work computer and don't have administrator privileges. So I unzipped the .NET CORE folder and placed it in a personal folder on my desktop. `C:\Users\(my.name)\Desktop\Me\dotnetcore`.
[image]

I then went into my Environment Variables for my user and added this to my `Path` variable.
[image]

Now I open VSCode and made a new folder for a project. It's in a Project folder in the same Desktop folder as my .NET Core "installation.
[image]

Now let's try to make a new ASP5 MVC WebApp! According to documentation, that command should be this.. `dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.0`, so lets run it in the VSCode Terminal.. Wait... WHAT?!
[image]

If anyone can help me out here, that would be wonderful :) Thanks in advance for your time.

Furthermore, if I open a standard windows command line and run `dotnet`, it seems to work correctly as shown here...
[image]

P.S I guess I didn't edit my name out the last two screenies, not a relevant point, just kinda funny I think lol.

As per Eric's request, here is the cmd output of `dotnet --info`..
[image]

Comment: dot net core experience is rather sensitive to exact versions at the moment. Does dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.1 work any better?

Comment: and, ignoring VSCode, what if you run the whole dotnet new command in the console instead?

Comment: Very sad. So, ignore VSCode completely and stay with commandline. If you get errors running `dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.0` (which does work on my machine) then your problem is with the dotnet core install.

Comment: I've never done the 'install without rights' that you've done, but you said you used the zip file: did you get SDK or runtime?

Comment: SDK, trying in command line

Comment: Command line didn't work either. Issue is still at large.

Comment: Can you tell me where you downloaded the .NET Core SDK from? You should have gotten it from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core. Also please list what gets shown from `dotnet --info`.

Comment: @EricErhardt that is exactly where I downloaded the SDK from. Windows (x64) Binaries .zip file. Including screenie of `dotnet --info` on the bottom of the question

Comment: @KeplerIO could you try running dotnet new --debug:reinit please? This forces all of the configuration for "new" to get rebuilt. Generally, we see this happen in cases where either the CLI is being built from source multiple times with the same version (or is uninstalled and then deployed via ZIP at the same version) or if the installation of dotnet has moved since the first run of "new" for that version. We've done a lot of hardening for this next release, so hopefully this won't be an issue going forward.

Comment: @mlorbetske hey after running `dotnet new --debug:reinit` I see a table with Templates, Short Name, Language, Tags, but there are no templates in that table... weird.. All my templates are missing it seems..

Comment: @KeplerIO that's normal, the engine's in the pre-initialized state, the next run will force it to recreate the configuration & there should be templates again

Comment: @KeplerIO I see from your answer that you were able to successfully create the template now but with a different value for framework - running the original command still produces this error?

Comment: @mlorbetske Yes, running my original command produces error still. Only got it to work by changing syntax of the command.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to reproduce your issue. There are the steps that I took.

[Download the Windows (x64) binaries](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) into `C:/temp`.

Then run the following from PowerShell (posh). If you aren't conformable with posh, doing the following manually is equivalent.

```
# Extract the downloaded zip into the C:\temp\dotnetcore directory.

cd C:\temp
Expand-Archive .\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.1.zip
New-Item -Type Directory dotnetcore
Copy-Item .\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.1\* -Recurse .\dotnetcore\

# Add the dotnetcore directory it to the machine's PATH.

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable
    ("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\temp\dotnetcore", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

# Rename dotnet.exe to my-dotnet.exe instead.
# This step is necessary because I already have dotnet installed.

Rename-Item .\dotnetcore\dotnet.exe my-dotnet.exe

# Create a new directory, in which to create MyApp.

New-Item -type Directory MyApp
```

Having done all that, open Visual Studio Code in the C:\temp\MyApp directory and run `my-dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.0` from the integrated CMD terminal.

[image: It works on my machine.]

If I were you, I would try the above steps to see whether you have a different outcome than I have.

Comment: Hmm in your terminal for VSCode it says your command line is cmd whilst mine says powershell.. I'll try to mess around with unpacking via posh

Comment: @KeplerIO The integrated terminal shell is configurable. I chose cmd in this answer because I want to load the PATH variable after modifying it with posh. Now that I know your using posh, I can give you additional posh related integrated terminal tips.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Core CLI was not accepting the syntax in which I typed my command. This is BS because I copied the command from documentation. The version of the command I was trying to run was `dotnet new mvc --auth None --framework netcoreapp1.1`, not `dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.0`. .NET Core needs to redocument it's CLI.